# Replacing couple of scroll bars with one

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-jscrollpane, tinyscrollbar

I have a situation where I have two divs with scroll bars and I need to get rid of them and have just one unified scrolling for both the divs. I am using JavaScript to synchronize the scrolling of two panes and have hidden one of the scrollbars using overflow:hidden. The scrollbar that is visible scrolls both the panes using the script.

http://jsfiddle.net/Amnesiac/ekT3h/5/

I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve this. I am open to using any external library or q jQuery plugin.

Comment: You could avoid vertical synchronization by putting both the divs inside a larger div, `#outerDiv`, which is scrollable. Of course, you'd still have to sync horizontally.

Whats the use case for this?

Comment: I have two fullcalendar widgets whose scrolling I need to synchronize. One of them displays the calendar (interview schedules)and the other displays resource view(interviewers free busy schedules). What you suggest may not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this plugin for years : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2009/03/19/synchronizing-scrollbars-using-jquery.aspx

```
jQuery.fn.synchronizeScroll = function() {

               var elements = this;
               if (elements.length <= 1) return;

              elements.scroll(
              function() {
                  var left = $(this).scrollLeft();
                  var top = $(this).scrollTop();
                  elements.each(
                  function() {
                      if ($(this).scrollLeft() != left) $(this).scrollLeft(left);
                      if ($(this).scrollTop() != top) $(this).scrollTop(top);
                  }
                  );
              });
          }
```

Comment: Bouillou, as I mentioned in the question I already have the scrip for synchronizng the scrollbars.